# Modal Bootstrap ASP button doesn't event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms, bootstrap-modal

I have bootstrap modal, there is `asp:Button` when I calling `OnClick` event doesn't work. I added on my button attribute `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` I calling event `OnClick` but my `TextBox` has value is empty. **Help me please!**

For modal bootstrap I use `link js`

```
<script src="/Content/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Content/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap-modalmanager.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
```

Here is my modal window

```
<div id="static" class="panel panel panel-info modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" style="display: none;">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        info
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">

                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">                         
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="testе" ></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 text-left">
            <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-link">close</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 text-right">
            <asp:Button ID="btnDownload" runat="server"  OnClick="btnDownload_Click" class="btn btn-success" Text="downl"></asp:Button>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my OnClick()

```
protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string tets = testе.Text; 

    }
```

Comment: We will need more code than this. Which on-click doesn't work: client side or server side? Are there any errors in the javascript console? How have you wired up OnClick? Provide just enough code for us to replicate the problem.

Comment: @JonP, I update my question, I don't get any erroes in the js consloe.

Comment: @JonP Help me please!!!